# C# Official MongoDB Connector - Check if user has already liked a post

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

How do I check if author exists in a nested array.
My Models looks like this:

```
public class Likes
{
    // - Id is equal to article ID
    [Required]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Like[] likes { get; set; }
}


public class Like
{
    [Required]
    public string author { get; set; }

    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

In Bson format is looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5733d90aa75c955354bc2057"),
    "likes" : [ 
        {
            "author" : "admin@admin.com",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-05-12T12:27:02.315Z")
        }, 
        {
            "author" : "admin@admin.com",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-05-12T12:27:03.610Z")
        }, 
        {
            "author" : "admin@admin.com",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-05-12T12:27:04.185Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see. Same person can like the same post. How can I check if eg admin@admin.com exists in likes list for a given post?

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can simply use query expressions. Check some way like this:

```
var exists= ikes.likes.where(p=>p.Id='xxx').Any(x=>x.authod.Equals('author'))
```